# Calculating sum of rows in matrix

Tags: c, matrix

The sum of rows part just doesn't work properly . Any suggestions? 
Also if the main diagonal is i==j, what will be the opposite diagonal ? How do i define it?

```
int main (void) {
    int A[5][5];       
    int B[5];
    int x=0,sum=0;
    int n,m,i=0,j;

    printf("Enter rows and columns : \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    printf("Enter matrix : \n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {               
        for (j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* Sum of rows Problem */
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        B[i] = 0;         
        for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) {
            B[i] = B[i] + A[i][j];
            ++i;        
        }
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {                        
        for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) {        
            printf("The sum of rows %d \n", B[j]);
        }
    }      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, there is no question here, and also your code was a huge mess, i wasted like 2 min formatting it, what are you trying to ask? and you can think about the opposite diagonal!

Comment: Why do you do `++i;` inside the inner loop?

Comment: Yea I forgot to ask you what Inspired asked you, what is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @iharob Im kind of learning matrixes , so im trying to get a piece of information on diagonals , so ok if you dont want to share your intellect.

Comment: It's not about sharing anything, it's just that you shouldn't try to learn programming if you don't know about matrices, and in any case, format your code better, someone has gave you an answer, it's correct I think, pick it when the system allows you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you just have to remove `++i` inside the inner loop, and the program runs fine.

Code:

```
int main (void) {
    int A[5][5];       
    int B[5];
    int x=0,sum=0;
    int n,m,i=0,j;

    printf("Enter rows and columns : \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    printf("Enter matrix : \n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {               
        for (j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* Sum of rows Problem */
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        B[i] = 0;         
        for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++) {
            B[i] = B[i] + A[i][j];    //Removed the stray ++i from here.   
        }
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {                                
            printf("The sum of row %d is %d \n",i+1,B[i]);
    }      
    return 0;
}
```

And answering your second question, the **opposite diagonal** is `i == size - j- 1` if `size` is the size of the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! You are the best , straight to the point .. love it!